# Problemas con Crystal Report en Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Buenas espero puedan ayudarme, tengo problemas con el crystal report que le instale a mi visual studio 2012 Ultimate como pueden ver en la imagen al momento de agregar el crystal report me sale esa ventana y no se a que pueda deberse [image: Imagen error]

Answer (score 1):

debes instalar las herramientas de desarrollo para Crystal Reports en tu VisualStudio
https://www.sap.com/products/crystal-visual-studio.html

En este enlace de arriba puedes descargarlo, recuerda, ¡descarga las Herramientas de desarrollo!

Link directo:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_22.exe